# Rails Active Record Queries - Not Equal and Blank/Empty Strings

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an active record query with a Not Equal clause for a string. For example:

```
 Post.where.not(title: "Rails 4")
```

or

```
 Post.where("title != ?", "Rails 4")
```

However, if the title is empty or blank it will not be included in the results. **How can I also include the records that have a blank or empty title?**

For example:

**Posts**

```
id => 1, title => "Rails 4"
id => 2, title => ""
id => 3, title => "Rails 3"
```

**Actual Result:**

```
Post.where.not(title: "Rails 4") #=> [3]
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Post.where.not(title: "Rails 4") #=> [2, 3]
```

Comment: What database are you using? In postgres, `where.not(title: 'Rails 4')` would return the desired rows (#2 and #3) if the #2 title is an empty string (as you indicate). If the title for #2 is null then the result will be skipped, as any comparison with null is always false. Please update question to specify the null value if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Have a try with below query

```
Post.where("title != ? OR title = ?", "Rails 4",'')
```

Comment: This will only return results that have blank title

Comment: @Babar Did you checked?

Comment: Problem is I don't have my system set up on my home pc. so I'll have to take your word for it.... but I don't know how its going to translate to fetch everything in the table except for 'RAILS 4'

Comment: I think changing the AND to OR should be the way

Comment: @Pavan thanks for the answer. I changed it a little as the following seems to also catch if it is a null value or if it is just an empty string: `Post.where("title != ? OR title IS NULL", "Rails 4")`. Any downsides to that change?

Comment: @diasks2 I think it should be `Post.where("title != ? OR title IS NULL OR title= ?", "Rails 4",'')`

Comment: `NULL` in not the same `''`

Comment: @pavan I don't think your answer is correct as it currently stands as it doesn't account for a null value which is part of the definition of blank in Rails

Comment: @diasks2 Is this worked for you `Post.where("title != ? OR title IS NULL OR title= ?", "Rails 4",'')`?

Answer (score 1):

****NOTE** I'm assuming you're using a database like postgres and that the issue you're having is with null values, not empty string values. If empty string values aren't being returned then you have an entirely different issue*

The reason `where.not(title: 'Rails 4')` doesn't return what you expect is that you have null values in the string field, and any comparison with null will be null, which is falsey.

**Posts**

```
id => 1, title => "Rails 4"
id => 2, title => ""
id => 3, title => "Rails 3"
id => 4, title => NULL
```

In order to include Post #4 in the results, you need to explicitly include null values. One way to do that is with `IS NULL`.

```
# Original - excludes rows with null title
Post.where.not(title: "Rails 4") #=> [2,3]
# SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE posts.title != 'Rails 4' 

# Option #1 - explicitly include null
Post.where.not(title: "Rails 4").or(Post.where(email: nil)) #=> [2,3,4]
# SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE (posts.title != 'Rails 4' OR posts.title IS NULL)

# Option #2 - replace null values with empty string
POST.where.not("coalesce(posts.title, '') = ?", 'Rails 4')
# SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE NOT (coalesce(posts.title, '') = 'Rails 4')
```

A third solution is to disallow null values in your string field entirely (with a `NOT NULL` constraint). Allowing null values in a string field can have other unexpected side-effects - for example, if you order your posts by 'email' then posts with a null email will show up in a different spot than you posts with an empty string email, but to the user it just looks confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually type the SQL here and possibly create a database dependency, or use ActiveRecord combined with [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel), which is a bit less readable, but works nicely:

```
table = Post.arel_table

Post.where(table[:title].not_eq('Rails 4').or(table[:title].eq('')))
```

Answer (score -1):

Pavans answer is correct, just use this

```
Post.where("title != ? OR title = ?", "Rails 4",'')
```

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is 7 years old but it still comes up on Google. A better solution is using reject instead of where.not

```
Post.all.reject{|x| x.title == "Rails 4"}
```

Comment: This loads every object in the database in memory and then iterates over each one. For large tables this may crash the server. Please use with caution.